# Factorial Algorithm in C: way to store result of previous iteration in a string?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, factorial

I'm just starting out with programming in C and I only know how to make some *very* simple programs in other languages.  Anyway, I'm making an iterative factorial calculator (current progress can be seen below) and I'm not sure how I'd go about storing "factorial_value" to be used in the next iteration of the loop.  If I run the code as is, then "factorial_value" will just reset itself to whatever `user_number * (user_number - step)` is equal to for that iteration rather than keeping the value form the previous iteration and multiplying that number by the number it succeeds.

***Is there some way where I can store the result of each iteration by appending it to a string and then extracting the appropriate value in    each following step?***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_number;
    int factorial_value = user_number;
    int step = 1;


    printf("Enter the nubmer you would like to get the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d!",&user_number);

    while (step < user_number) {
        factorial_value = factorial_value * (user_number - step);

        step++;
    }

    printf("\n%d! = %d\n",user_number,factorial_value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You initialise `factorial_value` with `user_number`, which is uninitialised. Initialise it with `1`. Your calculation is also off by one.

Comment: Note that a 32-bit unsigned integer can only store factorials up to 12!.  Although 64-bit integers go a bit bigger, you very quickly run out of bits.  Your loop is a slightly curious way of going about producing the answer; you might find it simpler with `factorial_value = 1; for (step = 2; step <= user_number; step++) factorial_value *= step;`

Comment: To answer your direct question: yes, there are ways to store the result(s) in a string or several strings and then extract values when required.  The question is 'why would you want to do so?'  Also, storing the numbers as a string will be slow.

Comment: @user1884124 : The problem solving strategy that you want to use is 
called dynamic programming. Its better to store the result in an 
integer array rather than as a string. Moreover dynamic programming is
expensive in terms of space since you will require more space to store
the calculated results, but its efficient in terms of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is correct, except that you are using the value of the variable `factorial_number` before it is initialized. You could store the number in a string and read it again, but it would be slow, more complex, and doesn't seem necessary, given the code you have shown us.

One way to fix the unitialized value is to assign `user_number` to it *after* it was read by `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_number;
    int factorial_value;  /* just declare it here */
    int step = 1;


    printf("Enter the nubmer you would like to get the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d!",&user_number);

    /* and now that user_number was rad, you can assign it to factorial_number: */
    factorial_value = user_number; 

    while (step < user_number) {
        factorial_value = factorial_value * (user_number - step);

        step++;
    }

    printf("\n%d! = %d\n",user_number,factorial_value);

    return 0;
}
```

But you may make your program a bit simpler if you multiply `factorial_number` by step in each iteration (see that I changed the condition from `<` to `<=` so the last number will be used). I also
changed the types to `unsigned long`, so you can calculate factorials of larger numbers (`int` is a short integer. `long` is longer, and `long long` may be even longer in bits; the `unsigned` modifier means you will not represent negative numbers, so *all* bits will be used to represent magnitude -- the range is 2 times larger than its `signed` counterpart).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_number;
    unsigned long long factorial_value = 1; /* starts with 1 */
    int step = 1;

    printf("Enter the nubmer you would like to get the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d!",&user_number);

    /* from one to user_number, including it: */
    while (step <= user_number) {
        /* multiply factorial_number by the current value of step: */
        factorial_value = factorial_value * step;
        step++;
    }

    printf("\n%d! = %llu\n",user_number,factorial_value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not setting `factorial_value` to `user_number` after getting it from user;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_number;
    int factorial_value;
    int step = 1;

    printf("Enter the nubmer you would like to get the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d!",&user_number);
    factorial_value = user_number;
    while (step < user_number) {
        factorial_value = factorial_value * (user_number - step);

        step++;
    }

    printf("\n%d! = %d\n",user_number,factorial_value);

    return 0;
}
```